# Heroku: custom domains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I had set up my custom domain on Heroku and it was working. Then I decided I wanted to delete that app but use the same domain on another app. I tried switching it over, but I got error messages saying it was already in use.

Therefore, I decided to start from scratch. I went to Godaddy, reset the nameservers (changing them to other nameservers and then back to Zerigo/Heroku) so that they were now pointing fresh at Zerigo.

I then added the domain to this new app but when i run the following in the terminal to check that it's been added properly.

```
host www.mydomain.com
```

I get this error

```
www.mydomain.com has address 67.63.50.58
Host www.mydomain.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
Host www.mydomain.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

This addresss 67.63.50.58 is not the heroku/zerigo address.

However, I'm quite sure that I know how to set up a custom domain. For example, i tested another custom domain on this same app (a custom domain that I hadn't assigned anywhere else previously) and it's now working fine.

Anyone know how I can reuse this custom domain i.e. totally reset it. Or can you explain what that error message means?

Answer (score 0):

If you get a message that the `domain is already in use` when you add the domain to a new app on Heroku that would suggest to me that when you deleted the application previously then for whatever reason Heroku did not delete the previous custom domains - you shouldn't have to change any DNS settings if the domain was already pointing at Heroku. I would contact support in this instance and tell them the scenario, they should be able to fix it.